# Jquery Ajax contact form within a Jqmodal ajax popup window

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, html, jqmodal

Hi all I am making a contact form popup window on my website using Jqmodal. The contact form loads and displays correctly, but the contact form itself I am trying to submit it using ajax and then want to give the user a message saying "message send" and slide the form up.

Anyway the main issue I am running into is that it submits the form but takes the user to the actual php file that it should of connected to via ajax. My code is as follows. It is probably something on the Jqmodal side of things but I am unsure if anyone could point me in the right direction that would be fantastic. Also close button is not working but I reckon I can fix that.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />

<!--[if IE]>
<script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

<script src="http://www.modernizr.com/downloads/modernizr.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#submit").click(function() {
        var action = $("#contact_form").attr('action');
        var form_data = {
            code:$("#code").val(),
            name:$("#name").val(),
            email:$("#email").val(),
            message:$("#message").val(),
            is_ajax:1
        };
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:action,
            data:form_data,
            success: function(response)
            {
                if(response == 'success')
                    $("#form").slideUp('slow', function() {
                        $("#message").html("<p class='success'>Your Message Has Been Sent.</p>");
                    });
                else
                    $("#message").html("<p class='error'>Code was typed incorecctly.</p>");
            }
        });
        return false;
    });

    // refresh captcha
    $('#refresh').click(function() {
        change_captcha();
    });

    function change_captcha(){
        document.getElementById('captcha').src="./static/classes/get_captcha.php?rnd="+Math.random();
    };
});
</script>
<link href="./static/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quantico:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

</head>
<body>
    <span id="close">
        <button class="jqmClose">Close</button>
    </span>
    <br/><br/>
    <form name="contact_form" method="POST" action="./static/classes/contact.php" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
        <input id="name" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Full Name..." required>
        <br/>
        <input id="email" name="email" type="email" placeholder="Your Email..." required>
        <br/>
        <input id="message" name="message" type="text" placeholder="Your Message..." required>
        <br/>
        <section id="captcha_area">
            <img src="./static/classes/get_captcha.php" alt="" id="captcha" />
            <br/>
            <input name="code" type="text" id="code">
        </section>
        <section id="refresh">?</section>
        <br clear="all" /><br clear="all" />
        <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Send">
    </form>
    <span id="message"></span>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `$("#submit").click(function() {` to => `$("#submit").click(function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();`. Rest of the code is same. This will stop default behavior of submit action.

OR you can use, [.submit](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) event.

Comment: Thanks a lot but its still keeps on taking the user to the contact.php page after pressing submit :/ I am still messing around with it to try to fix it myself but anymore advice would be awesome.

Comment: Your form doesn't have `id` attribute set to `contact_form` so, it does not have url for ajax request. Well I tried this, and it doesn't take me to php page.

Comment: check your javasscript on local machine, for errors. If it contains error at any point it'll just stop executing statements then on.

Comment: Yeah that was a stupid mistake but it was strange how it still knew where to submit to without the form ID being stated anyway I changed that and its still doing it so I am trying to figure it out still, most annoying of all I some how broke my captcha check always comes out wrong now and that was working a minute ago so I am trying to back track on myself.

Comment: This is driving me crazy now trying so many little things to get it working, if anyone wants to see the live version I am working on its here: http://pug4u.com/ click the contact us button at the top. I will keep trying.

Comment: **it still knew where to submit to without the form ID** Not actually, it was not making request to ajax as URL was empty.

Comment: This isn't really an answer to my problem with Jqmodal but I believe something its something that is fixable but I actually when with another solution using http://fancybox.net/ 

It is similar to Jqmodal but has some features Jqmodal doesn't have like the ability to use Iframe's very quick and easily. 

I am sorry if anyone is looking for an answer to my original question but I couldn't do it with Jqmodal so if your working on a project and encounter the problem I described you may want to consider: http://fancybox.net/